# Last decimal digit precision changes in different call of same generator function [python]

Tags: python, function, generator, floating-point-precision

I created this generator function:

```
def myRange(start,stop,step):
    r = start
    while r < stop:
        yield r
        r += step
```

and I use it in two different ways. 1st:

```
for x in myRange(0,1,0.1):
    print x
```

Result:

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
```

2nd way to call the function:

```
a = [x for x in myRange(0,1,0.1)]
```

which results in:

```
[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999]
```

Why are the values generated different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not the order in which you called your generator, but the way you are presenting the numbers that caused this change in output.

You are printing a *list* object the second time, and that's a container. Container contents are printed using `repr()`, while before you used `print` on the float *directly*, which uses `str()`

`repr()` and `str()` output of floating point numbers simply differs:

```
>>> lst = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999]
>>> print lst
[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999]
>>> for elem in lst:
...     print elem
... 
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
>>> str(lst[3])
'0.3'
>>> repr(lst[3])
'0.30000000000000004'
```

`repr()` on a float produces a result that'll let you *reproduce the same value accurately*. `str()` rounds the floating point number for presentation.

Comment: Wondering, though... Does this mean `repr()` is subject to the same floating point representation inaccuracy as detailed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)?

Comment: @Nanashi: of course it is. All that `repr()` does is reveal the actual float value, not round it to a human readable version.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that's how `repr()` works at all. This shed more light than an awful lot of other `repr() vs str()` tutorials I've read. Thanks!

Comment: @NullDev note that around Python 3.2, things changed so that for floating point numbers there's no difference between `str` and `repr`.  I've edited the relevant link into the duplicates list.